# Android to PC data exchange via adb

Tags: android

I've written an android application which reads database through the content providers. And now I want to display the database in a PC program. How can my PC program get the data gained by the android application? In other words, how to do data exchange between Android and PC via adb?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Go in `DDMS` perspective, then open the `File Explorer`, there you can find data directories of the applications and system. Navigate to `/data/data/you-package-name/databases`, the click the Pull out file from the phone icon, save it wherever you want on your PC.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do those things in program. So the data is not limited to database files, sometimes it may just be a String for example.

Comment: Well, you cannot extract a string from the program just as it is because, you must write that string to any file format that can carry data.

Answer (score 0):

Android will not let you send files from device to PC using ADB. You can use `adb pull` to get files, but there isn't a way for the device to push. It would be easier to make a simple TCP client/server setup that would send data via WiFi or 3G. If you really need to use USB, you may be able to use the new USB APIs in Android 3.1.